# MongoDB - How to model recursive relation (categories)

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongorepository

I'm working on an application that will have categories for it's entries. Each entry will have exactly one category. My concern is how to model categories in order to achieve that with the cleanest code and design.

This is how I was thinking to implement the Category entity - **Approach 1**:

```
public class Category : Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
    public int GuiOrder { get; set; }
    public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

In order to achieve nested categories and instantiate them in this way:

```
    var cat1 = new Category()
    {
        Name = "Bikes", 
        Desc = "Mountain, city, you-name-it we have it bikes.", 
        GuiOrder = 1,
        Categories = new List<Category>()
        {
            new Category()
            {
                Name = "Sub 1",
                Desc = "Sub 1 description.",
                GuiOrder = 1,
                //Id = 
            }
        }
    };
```

This is also how the document will look like in MongoDB. As you can see in the "Sub 1", Id is commented out, because with this entity definition for a nested category MongoDB will not generate a key, so I'll have to do it explicitly in application, with something like:

```
subCat1.Id = new BsonObjectIdGenerator().GenerateId(categoryRepository.Collection, subCat1).ToString();
```

and since I don't have reference to "subDocument1" in object initializer, that will have to be done later, probalz recursively before submitting an object. Which seems a bit awkward.

As an alternative, I could do a following entity definition (**Approach 2**):

```
public class Category : Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
    public int GuiOrder { get; set; }
    public Category Parent { get; set; }
}
```

Since now the categories are flattened this is really a relational approach and what I don't like here is that Mongo will insert whole objects, not the ObjectIds only:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("53413657e42c3c16582cda70"),
        "Name" : "Bikes",
        "Desc" : "Mountain, city, you-name-it we have it bikes.",
        "Parent" : null
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("53413657e42c3c16582cda72"),
        "Name" : "Sub 1",
        "Desc" : "Sub 1 description.",
        "Parent" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("53413657e42c3c16582cda70"),
                "Name" : "Bikes",
                "Desc" : "Mountain, city, you-name-it we have it bikes.",
                "Parent" : null
        }
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("53413657e42c3c16582cda73"),
        "Name" : "Sub 2",
        "Desc" : "Sub 2 description.",
        "Parent" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("53413657e42c3c16582cda70"),
                "Name" : "Bikes",
                "Desc" : "Mountain, city, you-name-it we have it bikes.",
                "Parent" : null
        }
}
```

So my concerns are:
For approach 1 - how I would seek through categories efficiently (they will be nested at about 4 levels)? Let's say for a feature: "Show all in this category"... Is assigning an ObejctId on application level very bad practice? I doubt that this will need sharding ever...

Or with approach 2 what if "main" category changes? - I'd have to change it on several places. Also with deep hirearchy that can get really messy and repetitive.

I would appreciate feedback on what solution is better and what are proposed improvements. Where I can expect problems with the one or another? For better picture - These categories will not be changing much (I might even not implement the UI for their manipulation).

Comment: This is discussed in the docs: http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/use-cases/category-hierarchy/ and here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/data-models-tree-structures/

Comment: And it looks like you need to adjust your data model to Bette reflect your storage requirements. Unlike the entity framework, MongoDb's serializer will storage the entire object. You'd need to change a `Parent` to store just the Id rather than the parent object. You can control that through a. `ShouldSerializeXYZ` pattern as shown in the C# docs.

Comment: Thanks @WiredPrairie, I did the reading.
So it's more of an solution 2 from my description.
But it's still a problem to me - looks like I have to store each category separately not all of them in a batch, so I can get the ObjectId and then I'll have a `ParentId` instead of `Parent`. `ShouldSerializeXYZ` will then not be required if only Id is stored. What do you think?